# ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS

Tags: elf, 32-bit, sparc

I have the below code which is extracted by using **stings** command.

I need to edit the code and compile. But I do not have any idea how to proceed.

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
%s/CMSlog_%02d%02d.log
%.20s  %7d    %02d:%02d:%02d  
%.2000s
%s/CMSrecvlog_%02d%02d.log
%.20s  %7d    %02d:%02d:%02d  
%.2000s
%0*lu
%c%c%.6s%.8s
%s/MacEB13%.4s
EB13 path =[%s]
Mac EB13 ERR [%s] open error
%s/EB13%.4s
stderr [%s] open error
%s/MacEB11%.4s
stderr [%s] open error
%s/EB11%.4s
stderr [%s] open error
mac path = [%s]
%s/MacEB21%.4s
stderr [%s] open error
%s/EB21%.4s
stderr [%s] open error
MacCalculate
%s/MacEB13%.4s
%s/MacEB21%.4s
%s/MacEB11%.4s
MacCalculate Error idx[%d]
Mac open stderr [%s] open error
%2d%2d
%2d%2d%2d
%4d%2d%2d
%02d%02d%02d
%04d%02d%02d
%2d%2d
%02d%02d
%02d
%04d
yymmdd
%02d%02d%02d
mmddyy
%02d%02d%02d
ddmmyy
%02d%02d%02d
yyyymmdd
%04d%02d%02d
mmddyyyy
%02d%02d%04d
ddmmyyyy
%02d%02d%04d
hhmmss
%02d:%02d:%02d
%s database open error !
%s file open error !
%s table open error !
Parameter input error !
Can't execute %s !
Can't describe %s !
Can't declare %s !
Can't prepare %s !
%s data error !
%s error !
%.2d
p_get_etra_date dchg = %d error
19%.6s
20%.6s
19%.4s
20%.4s
%02d%02d%02d
Usage [%s] kind sendfile cfgfile 
/data/applications/PgiWebApp/files/current/send/kftc/log
/data/applications/PgiWebApp/files/current/send/kftc/log
make directory error!!!
log directory is not exist!!
make new directory!!
get_config_file error[%.20s]
SENDER_NAME[%s]
PASS_WD[%s]
MAC1[%s]
MAC2[%s]
IP = [%s]
PORT = [%d]
KFTC
RKFTC
BKFTC
LKFTC
DKFTC
PKFTC
kind type error!!! [%s]
GiganCode [%s]
path [%.200s] NOT EXISTS !!
job_dir = [%s]
00%.4s
mac_day = [%s]
db_filename = [%s]
EB13
EB21
EB11
Mac job_kind error =[%d]
job_kind [%d]
22SENDER_NAME[%s]
PASS_WD[%s]
MAC1[%s]
MAC2[%s]
MAC LASTTotalSum = [%.10s]
600-001 respcode error %.3s
FAIL 600-001 respcode error!! check log file.
write_data=[%s]
new_protocol continue.. [%d] 
600-003 respcode error %.3s
FAIL 600-003 respcode error!! see log file.
transfer complete
600-004 respcode error %.3s
FAIL 600-004 respcode error!! see log file.
mv %s/%s %s/%s
SUCCESS[%s]
command[%s]
SUCCESS
All success
write buf= [%.*s] len [%d]
write error [%.150s] ret %d sock %d err %d
socket write error!!
read error len %d
socket read error!! check log file!!
CDATA=[%.4s]
11READ ERROR.. len %d
socket read error!! check log file!!
data = [%.*s] r_length=[%d]
msgtype = [%.4s]
%s/%.8s
fopen error [%s]
File open error!! check [%s] file!!
630 respcode error %.3s
630 respcode error!! check log file.
ex_size[%.12s] rec640[%.12s]
 fu_size is [%d]
%04ld
%04ld
%04ld
tran_byte = [%.4s]
gubun_code = [%.3s]
gigan_code = [%.8s]
%04d
tran_code = [%.4s]

%.8s
%.8s
%.8s
respcode = [%.3s]
%04d
%04d
%03d
%03ld
%04d
%03d
%04d
%04d
record_num =[%d], idx=[%d], sum_total=[%d]
signal [%d] encountered !!!!
pp value is [%d] in fseek
FLOW ret =[%d] blok_sz =[%d] block_no =[%d] teq_no =[%d]
file_pointer =[%d]
read error len %d
socket read error!!
temp=[%.4s]
r_length = [%ld]
READ ERROR.. len %d
socket read error!!
0300
Unknown Msgtype [%.4s] So I am Dead...
unknown msgtype!! check log file.
%02d%02d%02d
%02d%02d%02d
%.8s
%.8s
%.8s
%.12ld
%.4ld
error on open socket  
oops: --> socket error
600-004 respcode error %.3s
600-004 respcode error!! check log file.
Check config file 
File=[%s], 
 no search env file 
 no search env file 
 no search env file = 
GIGWAN_CODE%d
 no search env file 
SEND_PATH%d
 no search env file 
SEND_ERR_PATH%d
 no search env file 
HISTORY_SEND_PATH%d
 no search env file 
MAC_SEND_PATH%d
 no search env file 
 no search env file 
 no search env file 
 no search env file 
 no search env file 
 no search env file 
 no search env file 
 no search env file 
 no search env file 
 no search env file 
 no search env file 
 no search env file 
 no search env file 
 no search env file 
 no search env file 
 no search env file 
 no search env file 
 no search env file 
%.9s_SENDER_NAME_LEN
 no search env file 
%.9s_SENDER_NAME
 no search env file 
%.9s_PASS_WD
 no search env file 
%.9s_MAC_KEY1
 no search env file 
%.9s_MAC_KEY2
 no search env file 
 no search env file 
%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d
/usr/sbin/sendmail -t
fopen err
from: %s
to : %s
subject: [DATA] [%s] [%s] [%.6s] [%.6s]
[%s] [%s] [%.6s] [%.6s]
/data/applications/PgiWebApp/files/current/send/kftc/log
/data/applications/PgiWebApp/files/current/recv/kftc/log
START!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
config file
yymmdd
TARGET_IP_ADDR
TARGET_PORT
GIGWAN_COUNT
SENDER_ID
RECEIVE_ID
BLOCK_SIZE
DATA_LENGTH1
DATA_LENGTH2
KFTC_TEMP_PATH
RKFTC_TEMP_PATH
BKFTC_TEMP_PATH
LKFTC_TEMP_PATH
DKFTC_TEMP_PATH
PKFTC_TEMP_PATH
KFTC_PATH
RKFTC_PATH
BKFTC_PATH
LKFTC_PATH
DKFTC_PATH
PKFTC_PATH
SCRIPT_PATH
```

Also I do not have any idea what the above code is trying to do.

It would be really helpful if anyone can:

1. Explain the code.
2. How to decompile
3. how to compile after the changes.

Thanks,
Anish

Answer (score 2):

> I have the below code which is extracted by using stings command.
>   I need to edit the code and compile.

Your first step should be: find someone who has a clue. It is unlikely that you'll achieve whatever you are trying to do on your own.

That said, `strings` does *not* extract code, it only extracts printable strings from the code. Therefore there is *no* code to explain. (You should also read `man strings` if you are to understand anything.)

Assuming you still have the original binary, and not just the `strings` output, you can disassemble that binary using `objdump -d` (*do* read `man objdump` as well). *That* output, if it is small enough, you can hope someone would be able to understand and explain to you (you could also try to understand it yourself, armed with `SPARC` assembly manual, such as [this one](http://www.cse.scu.edu/~atkinson/teaching/sp05/259/sparc.pdf)).

Once you understand what the program does, you could write an equivalent program in `C`, and finally modify it to do whatever you want. But it may be simpler to write such a program from scratch, rather than going through decompile / modify route.